# In Maze Runner, why do runners wear these leather vests/belts over their clothing?

Tags: the-maze-runner

Is it just for the looks or is there some other reason for it? [image]

Comment: A regular belt stops your trousers from falling down. Logic then dictates that in the world of the Maze Runner, these belts stop their shirts from falling up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the straps are used to hold stuff onto them, in the picture you included the guy on the right has what appears to be a knife handle above his left shoulder. You can actually see that clearer in the below picture and the straps also have a bag at the bottom of them.

[image]

Also in this next picture you can see that the straps have a bag on them covering the whole of the back.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An interview with the film's costume designer identifies their use and function.

> **Q. It is reported that the leather holsters and breast plates were custom made for the film. What were the main considerations related to making these?**
>
> **Simonetta Mariano:** *As for their hand made harnesses, they are timeless. I have designed these particular pieces for practical reasons as well as because it looks so cool! **The runners needed at all time to have their hands and feet free for climbing, grabbing things, run and defending/escaping them self against the Grievers. Their harnesses served to hold and carry whichever accessories, water, map, and tools they needed without being a burden or in their way.***
>
> *During fittings the harnesses were the very first things each boys wanted to put on… It was quite funny… They felt like they were wearing some sort or armour or chest plate. It was some sort of a competition of who was wearing the cooler stuff. They all wanted more but Wess kept it simple.*
>
> <sub><sup>[THE MAZE RUNNER COSTUME DESIGN (INTERVIEW WITH SIMONETTA MARIANO)](https://www.shopyourtv.com/the-maze-runner-costume-design-interview-with-simonette-mariano/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the book, leather only appears in the form of a loop with which Ben is tied to a pole and forced into banishment. There is also no mention of vests or belts. When the Runners go out into the Maze, they carry **backpacks** full of supplies:

> Minho continued talking. "Here's a backpack, water bottles, lunch pack, some shorts and T-shirts, other stuff."

From the lack of these contraptions in the book, I would assume that they have replaced the backbacks in the movie as part of the visual design. They have no other purpose than to look cool (or stupid, depending on your tastes).

Comment: `They have no other purpose than to look cool`: Except as I point out in my answer they are backpacks...